# Как подгрузить модуль pandas в exe?

Tags: python, pandas

Собрал проект с помощью `pyinstaller -F -i "C:\Users\User\Desktop\project\com.ico" -w "main.py" -F -w` на выходе получил .exe но выдаёт ошибку [image]

как подгрузить его в exe?

Comment: огосподи. Да зачем же вы все пытаетесь делать экзешники? ну зачем? вы свой гениальный код прячете? От конкурентов? Короче, компилировать скрипты питона в экзешники - противоестественно, и Вселенная вам даёт очередное знамение.

Comment: @strawdog ну во-первых это "красивое")

Comment: Всякое такое смотрели, пробовали? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109324/pyinstaller-and-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том что нужные либы я устанавливал в pycharm для сборки было необходимо установить их в сам python. Всё решилось переходом в консоле в папку Scripts и устанокой pandas

> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts>pip install pandas

Так же main.py (он еденственный) скопировал из проекта pycharm в папку на рабочем столе и собирал там.